# How to use multi range in between rule of VeeValidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vee-validate

How to use multi range in between rule or included of  VeeValidate ?

i would like to validate 1-15 and 100

Eq.
5 is valid
50 is invalid
100 is valid

i try

rule.between = [[1,15],100];
not work but error message is "The XXX field must be between 1,15 and 100."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using custom validator:

```
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';

// Define custom validation rule
Validator.extend('custom-val', {
    getMessage: field => `The ${field} field must be between 1,15 and 100.`,
    validate: value => value === 100 || (value >= 1 && value <= 15)
});
```

Then use this validation rule as:

```
<input type="text" name="my-field" v-validate="'custom-val'">
```

Comment: i use Validator.extend('custom-val', {
    getMessage: field => `The ${field} field must be between 1,15 and 100.`,
    validate: value => value == 100 || (value >= 1 && value <= 15)
});